# Socket.io can't send two consecutive messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io for a project of mine, and i seem to be having trouble when sending two consecutive messages to the same socket. The idea is that when the user logs inn, i send him all messages which was sent to him while he wasn't connected, which can result in several .emit calls in the same method. However, the client seems to not receive these messages, or at least not understand that he has received them... Sending the messages independantly works fine however...

here is the output from the server console:

```
debug: xhr-polling writing �104�5:::
{"name":"friend_request","args":
[{"_id":"4fb040147185a2e21f000002","email":"made_up@gmail.com"}]}�201�6:::6+
[{"_id":"4fb91f732f869a6f16000004","socketId":"12602175611929481375","email":"casablanca@gmail.com",
"friends":[],"recentOpponents":[],"games":[]}]
```

Is this a bug in socket.io or am I doing something wrong? The behaviour is easily reproduceable by just calling .emit two consecutive times...

Oh and btw. Socket.io version 0.9.6 and NodeJS 0.6.17

Comment: Further investigations reveals that this only happens with the webbrowser in android 2.2 (which is my target device). Android 4.0.3 and Safari 5.1 (websocket) seems unencombered with the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the issue seemed to be i hadn't added  to my html file. Socket.io uses a unicode character to indicate a payload, so if you're using ASCII encoding (default) this will render you unable to receive multiple messages (which can happen when using ajax long-polling).